# Configure amplify-flutter for existing User pool without Cognito Identity pool

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, amplify-flutter

How to configure aws amplify in flutter for an existing user pool? There is no identity pool configured for this user pool. I want to configure it without creating an identity pool. Following is my current `amplifyconfiguration.dart` file,

```
const amplifyConfig = ''' {
  "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "auth": {
      "plugins": {
          "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
              "IdentityManager": {
                  "Default": {
                    
                  }
              },
              "CognitoUserPool": {
                  "Default": {
                      "PoolId": "**********",
                      "AppClientId": "**********",
                      "Region": "**********"
                  }
              },
              "Auth": {
                  "Default": {
                      "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}''';
```

Every time I try to signIn I get this error with above config,

```
Amplify.Auth.signIn(
      username: 'test@gmail.com',
      password: 'test'
    );

java.lang.Exception: Federation is not enabled, please check if you have CognitoIdentity configured.
```

How can I fix this without using a identity pool?